# How do I only select DIV with similar ID

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am parsing a poorly designed web page using beautiful soup.

At the moment, what I need is the select the comment section of the web page but each comment is treated as a DIV and each have an ID like "IAMCOMMENT_00001" but that's it. No class (This would have helped a lot).

So I am forced to search for all DIVs that start with "IAMCOMMENT" but I can't figure out how to do this. The closest I could find is SoupStrainer but couldn't understand how to even use it.

How would I be able to achieve this?

Comment: post your attempts. Show your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to parse form comments, first you need to find the comment of the your html. A way to do this is like:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment

soup = BeautifulSoup(myhtml)
comments = soup.find_all(text=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment))
```

to find the `div`s inside a comment,

```
for comment in comments:
    cmnt_soup = BeautifulSoup(comment)
    divs = cmnt_soup.find_all('div', attrs={"id": re.compile(r'IAMCOMMENT_\d+')})

    # do things with the divs
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `BeautifulSoup's` built in `find_all` function:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(yourhtml)
soup.find_all('div', id_=re.compile('IAMCOMMENT_'))
```